# User getting this on boot up of High Sierra

Tags: macos-highsierra

[High Sierra symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEwxr.png)

any ideas what this means?  I have tried to search for folder with prohibit, but only see things related to boot issues.

Comment: Is this a guest user?

Comment: It the main user.